# Can I change MQ Object Authority when it stopped

Tags: ibm-mq

I have some **stopped** QMGRs. When I try to start them or delete them from MQ Explorer, I encounter this error:

```
AMQ7077: You are not authorized to perform the requested operation.
exitvalue=119
```

How can I change or remove the restrictions on this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that I can do this by command `STRMQM 'qmName'` or `DLTMQM 'qmName'` as an alternative to using MQ Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

You can start or delete a queue manager via the MQ Explorer too, so long as the queue manager and MQ Explorer are running on the same machine/installation. You must ensure that the MQ Explorer is running under an mqm user ID, just as you needed to do run the `strmqm` or `dltmqm` commands.